# An XML stats page for my game

Tags: android, xml

I am making a stats page for my Android game, and I have never really used the Android XML layout stuff, so I'm sure things are a little messy and strange.  The layout ends up looking pretty good, and I'm just seeing if I can remove some of the repetitive crap and maybe better understand some of the stuff I did that seemed a little strange.

**stats**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:stretchColumns="*"
             android:layout_weight="1">
    <TableRow android:background="@drawable/red_background">
        <TextView
                android:text="STATS"
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="30dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_span="3"
                />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
    <TableRow android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_span="3">
            <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/red_background">
                <TableRow android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                <TableRow
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_gravity="center">
                    <TextView android:text="Score:"
                              android:textColor="#FF0000"
                              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                              android:textSize="20dip"
                              android:textStyle="bold"
                            />
                    <TextView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                              android:textColor="#0000FF"
                              android:textSize="20dip"
                              android:textStyle="bold"
                              android:id="@+id/Score"
                            />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_gravity="center">
                    <TextView android:text="Sliced:"
                              android:textColor="#FF0000"
                              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                              android:textSize="20dip"
                              android:textStyle="bold"
                            />
                    <TextView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                              android:textColor="#0000FF"
                              android:textSize="20dip"
                              android:textStyle="bold"
                              android:id="@+id/Sliced"
                            />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_gravity="center">
                    <TextView android:text="Scorched:"
                              android:textColor="#FF0000"
                              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                              android:textSize="20dip"
                              android:textStyle="bold"
                            />
                    <TextView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                              android:textColor="#0000FF"
                              android:textSize="20dip"
                              android:textStyle="bold"
                              android:id="@+id/Scorched"
                            />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_gravity="center">
                    <TextView android:text="Frozen:"
                              android:textColor="#FF0000"
                              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                              android:textSize="20dip"
                              android:textStyle="bold"
                            />
                    <TextView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                              android:textColor="#0000FF"
                              android:textSize="20dip"
                              android:textStyle="bold"
                              android:id="@+id/Frozen"
                            />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_gravity="center">
                    <TextView android:text="Bowled:"
                              android:textColor="#FF0000"
                              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                              android:textSize="20dip"
                              android:textStyle="bold"
                            />
                    <TextView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                              android:textColor="#0000FF"
                              android:textSize="20dip"
                              android:textStyle="bold"
                              android:id="@+id/Bowled"
                            />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
    <TableRow>
        <Button android:background="@drawable/blue_background"
                android:text="Quit"
                android:id="@+id/quit"
                android:textSize="30dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#0000FF"
                android:onClick="onClick"/>
        <Button android:background="@drawable/blue_background"
                android:text="Play"
                android:id="@+id/play"
                android:textSize="30dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#0000FF"
                android:onClick="onClick"/>
        <Button android:background="@drawable/blue_background"
                android:text="Post"
                android:id="@+id/post"
                android:textSize="30dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#0000FF"
                android:onClick="onClick"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

**blue_background**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape     android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners  android:radius="5dip" />
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
            <stroke  android:width="5dip" android:color="#0000FF"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**red_background**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape     android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners  android:radius="5dip" />
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
            <stroke  android:width="5dip" android:color="#FF0000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all I tried to change outer `TableLayout` to `RelativeLayout` and that's what I've got

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/red_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="STATS"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textSize="30dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomButtons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/quit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_background"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="Quit"
            android:textColor="#0000FF"
            android:textSize="30dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/play"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_background"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="Play"
            android:textColor="#0000FF"
            android:textSize="30dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/post"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_background"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="Post"
            android:textColor="#0000FF"
            android:textSize="30dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomButtons"
        android:layout_below="@id/topButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/red_background"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Score:"
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                android:textSize="20dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Score"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="10"
                android:textColor="#0000FF"
                android:textSize="20dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Sliced:"
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                android:textSize="20dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Sliced"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="1000"
                android:textColor="#0000FF"
                android:textSize="20dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Scorched:"
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                android:textSize="20dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Scorched"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="10000"
                android:textColor="#0000FF"
                android:textSize="20dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Frozen:"
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                android:textSize="20dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Frozen"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="1000000"
                android:textColor="#0000FF"
                android:textSize="20dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Bowled:"
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                android:textSize="20dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Bowled"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="1000000000000"
                android:textColor="#0000FF"
                android:textSize="20dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It seems to me that user will see is exactly the same [image: screen]

After these changes I wanted to understand if this layout is faster or not. For this purpose we need [`hierarchyviewer` tool from Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html).

Your layout based on `TableLayout` has:

- 29 views
- Measure: 27,508ms
- Layout: 0,525ms
- Draw: 17,195ms

[image: table_time]

The full hierarchy can be viewed here [image: table_hierarchy]

Layout based on `RelativeLayout` has:

- 22 views
- Measure: 12,150ms
- Layout: 0,395ms
- Draw: 16,446ms

[image: relative_time]

And the full hierarchy [image: relative_hierarchy]

As a conclusion we can say that the less views we have the faster the layout is. And in this case `RelativeLayout` is a little bit faster than `TableLayout`

Comment: Thanks, I like it, those `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` clauses were definitely something I did not know about.